# Asynchronous issue using rxjs chaining in ngrx effects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public setJwtDataParcoursPage = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(INIT_FORM_SUCCESS_ACTION),
  map((action: InitFormSuccessAction) => action.payload),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(this._apiHeadersSelector.getJwt) as Observable<string>),
  switchMap(([payload, jwt]: [InitResponse, string]) => {
    const params = { jwt, userId: payload.jwt.user.id }
    return forkJoin([
      of(payload),
      iif(
        () => payload.subscriptionManagement,
        this.subscriptionService.getSubscriptionInfo(params).pipe(map(subscription => subscription.body)),
        of(null)
      )
    ])
  }),
  map(([payload, subscriptionData]) => {
    const subscriptionStatus = this.getValue(subscriptionData?.status, payload.jwt.env.subscriptionManagement);
    this._analyticsService.updateParcoursVars(payload, subscriptionStatus, "parcours", "form");
    this.store.dispatch(new GetSubscriptionInfoSuccessAction(subscriptionData))
  }),
  catchError(_ => {
    ...
    return of([])
  })
);
```

I have other tasks happening in //.

When `payload.subscriptionManagement` =`false` everything is working as I expect. I mean  the chaining is not getting interrupted by other // tasks .

But When `payload.subscriptionManagement` =`true` the code is not getting immediatly to the last

`map(([payload, subscriptionData]) => {..`

It gets back later to this part.

My question how can I edit this code in order to keep the chaining inunterrupted ?

**Update** I have tried this way :

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public setJwtDataParcoursPage = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(INIT_FORM_SUCCESS_ACTION),
  map((action: InitFormSuccessAction) => action.payload),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(this._apiHeadersSelector.getJwt) as Observable<string>),
  switchMap(([payload, jwt]: [InitResponse, string]) => {
    const params = { jwt, userId: payload.jwt.user.id }
    return forkJoin([
      of(payload),
      iif(
        () => payload.jwt.env.subscriptionManagement,
        of(this.subscriptionService.getSubscriptionInfo(params)),
        of(null)
      )
    ])
  }),
  map(([payload, subscriptionData]) => {
    subscriptionData.subscribe(subscription => {

      const subscriptionStatus = this.getValue(subscription?.body.status, payload.jwt.env.subscriptionManagement);
      this._analyticsService.updateParcoursVars(payload, subscriptionStatus, "parcours", "form");
      this.store.dispatch(new GetSubscriptionInfoSuccessAction(subscription.body))
    })
}),
```

Now when `payload.subscriptionManagement` =`true` I get into

`map(([payload, subscriptionData]) => {` but the effect is getting interrupted when `subscribe`

Comment: There might be an issue is you are getting an error but you are not handling it using subscribe methods `next, error`, try to do it that way and check whether you are getting an error.

Comment: I have tried using next , error, I don't get errors , May be it's because that `of(null)` is synchronous observable  and  `this.subscriptionService.getSubscriptionInfo(params)` is async observable ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over complicating this. I don't think you really need the `forkJoin`. Also, I recommend that instead of mapping after the `switchMap` that you just use the `tap` off of observable you are switching to. No need to use `map` because you are not dispatching from the effect in every case. The sample below may not be perfect, but it should get you going in the right direction.

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public setJwtDataParcoursPage = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(INIT_FORM_SUCCESS_ACTION),
  map((action: InitFormSuccessAction) => action.payload),
  concatLatestFrom() => (this.store.select(this._apiHeadersSelector.getJwt) as Observable<string>), 
  switchMap(([payload, jwt]: [InitResponse, string]) => {
    const params = { jwt, userId: payload.jwt.user.id }

    if (!payload.subscriptionManagement) {
      const subscriptionStatus = this.getValue(null, payload.jwt.env.subscriptionManagement);
      this._analyticsService.updateParcoursVars(payload, subscriptionStatus, "parcours", "form");
      return;
    }
    return this.subscriptionService.getSubscriptionInfo(params).pipe(
      map(subscription => subscription.body),
      tap((subscriptionData) => {
        const subscriptionStatus = this.getValue(subscriptionData?.body.status, payload.jwt.env.subscriptionManagement);
        this._analyticsService.updateParcoursVars(payload, subscriptionStatus, "parcours", "form");
        this.store.dispatch(new GetSubscriptionInfoSuccessAction(subscriptionData?.body))
      })
    );
  }),
  catchError(_ => {
    ...
    return EMPTY
  })
);
```

Also, you [should be using `concatLatestFrom`](https://ngrx.io/guide/operators/operators#concatlatestfrom). It's also [recommended to use `createEffect` now](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#writing-effects).